# Numpy - index groups of rows into higher dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D array and I'd like to transform it into a 3D array where each row of the new array contains multiple rows of the original 2D array.

This code replicates the functionality (each row of the output array contains 3 rows of the input array) but I'm just wondering what the correct way to do this is and I think a more correct way of indexing would be faster for large datasets.

```
input = np.arange(100) + np.arange(100)[:,None]
output = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: input[x[0]:x[0]+3], 1, np.arange(100-2)[:,None])
```

The `input` array looks like this:

```
array([[  0,   1,   2, ...,  97,  98,  99],
       [  1,   2,   3, ...,  98,  99, 100],
       [  2,   3,   4, ...,  99, 100, 101],
       ...,
       [ 97,  98,  99, ..., 194, 195, 196],
       [ 98,  99, 100, ..., 195, 196, 197],
       [ 99, 100, 101, ..., 196, 197, 198]])
```

And the `output` array looks like this:

```
array([[[  0,   1,   2, ...,  97,  98,  99],
        [  1,   2,   3, ...,  98,  99, 100],
        [  2,   3,   4, ...,  99, 100, 101]],

       [[  1,   2,   3, ...,  98,  99, 100],
        [  2,   3,   4, ...,  99, 100, 101],
        [  3,   4,   5, ..., 100, 101, 102]],

       [[  2,   3,   4, ...,  99, 100, 101],
        [  3,   4,   5, ..., 100, 101, 102],
        [  4,   5,   6, ..., 101, 102, 103]],

       ...,

       [[ 95,  96,  97, ..., 192, 193, 194],
        [ 96,  97,  98, ..., 193, 194, 195],
        [ 97,  98,  99, ..., 194, 195, 196]],

       [[ 96,  97,  98, ..., 193, 194, 195],
        [ 97,  98,  99, ..., 194, 195, 196],
        [ 98,  99, 100, ..., 195, 196, 197]],

       [[ 97,  98,  99, ..., 194, 195, 196],
        [ 98,  99, 100, ..., 195, 196, 197],
        [ 99, 100, 101, ..., 196, 197, 198]]])
```

Comment: `input` is `np.arange(100) + np.arange(100)[:, None]`, right? And output shape is `(98, 3, 100)`?

Comment: Wow, that is way cleaner (I'm rusty on my numpy so I updated the question).  But yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, you can initialize `input` identically to what you have with just simple broadcasting:

```
ainput = np.arange(100) + np.arange(100)[:, None]
```

You should never have to transpose a symmetric array, or name variables that shadow built-in functions.

You can get the output without loops (which is what [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) does under the hood) using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
n = 3
aoutput = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ainput, shape=(ainput.shape[0] - n + 1, n, ainput.shape[1]), strides=(ainput.strides[0], *ainput.strides))
```

This basically says to view `ainput` as an array of the required shape, with the new dimension having a stride of one row in the original array. That means that the memory of the different layers overlap, and if you decide to write to this array, you may see the change in three places at once.

As of numpy version 1.20, there is a thin wrapper that does the same thing: [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html). It allows you to work in terms of the window size and axes, without having to compute the shape and strides manually:

```
aoutput = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(ainput, (3, 100), axis=(0, 1))
```

Comment: So I'm not looking to jump rows.  `aoutput` has rows 3-5 of `ainput` on its second row but I want rows 1-4 on the second row.  I'm not exactly sure what the shape passes as `strides` above is doing.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah. Updated. Strides is the number of bytes between elements in a given dimension

Comment: Beautiful.  Points awarded

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah. I do like points. I updated with an easier-to-use alternative